# PHP : insert executable php code in HTML

Tags: php, include, ob-start

I got simple caching script which is saving php code into HTML. Everything works fine, but I need to add dynamic tracking code into every saved HTML by including a script from another file with include() statement

```
....

$s_getdata = http_build_query( array(
                   'cat' => 'CAT1',
                   'buffit'=>'TRUE',
                 )
             );
$s_page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/buffer.php?'.$s_getdata);
ob_start();
echo $s_page;
file_put_contents('./index.html', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
```

I tried to add this code before ob_start, but it just add code as simple text  in string (not working) :

```
$s_page .= '<?php include("./tr/in.php"); ?>';
```

Any idea how to do it ? Thanks!

Comment: php will not execute in .html files.. whats in `./tr/in.php` maybe you can do a file_get_contents if its just html or do the buffering capture again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by 2 ways,

**Option 1:** return value as a function from the `in.php` file,

your `in.php` file code,

```
function dynatrack() {
   // your dynamic tracking code generation here
   return $code; // where $code is your dynamic tracking code
}
```

Your original file,

```
$s_page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/buffer.php?'.$s_getdata);
include("./tr/in.php");
$s_page .= dynatrack();
```

**Option 2:** Get the contents of the `in.php` file by using `file_get_contents` again,

```
$s_page = file_get_contents('http://example.com/buffer.php?'.$s_getdata);
$s_page .= file_get_contents('./tr/in.php');
```

I hope this helps!